# Is it possible to deserialize java object in javascript

Tags: java, javascript, node.js, serialization

In order to communicate with legacy project,  I need to deserialise a Java object in a Node app.

Is it possible to deserialise Java objects in JavaScript?

The original serialization is done through Java interface `Externalizable`.

Comment: How are you serializing it?

Comment: Your question lack information. How do you serialize your data in the first place?

Comment: You might look into something like https://github.com/joeferner/node-java to deserialize the Java object and then reserialize using JSON.

Comment: The original serialization is done through Java interface Externalizable.

Answer (score 2):

No, I don't think it is possible to do it directly.

The [format](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2072752/the-java-serialization-algorithm-revealed.html) of a serialized Object (either via Serializable or Externalizable) is java specific.

You have either to create a parser for the java Externalizable format or deserialize it in java and then transform it in a format like parseable with javascript like JSON using a JSON framework like [jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org).

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't know a complete and updated library to do it, I know about https://www.npmjs.com/package/java-deserialization.

It's easy to use if you don't have any fancy java class serialized.

```
var javaDeserialization = require("java-deserialization");
var objects = javaDeserialization.parse(buf);
```